# Verify which method was called on itself using MOQ?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

The object I'm testing will invoke other methods on itself depending on something.

I.e.

```
class ToTest {
 public void A(MyObject o) {
  if (some_condition)
   this.B(o);
  else 
   this.C(o);
 }
 public void B(MyObject o) { ... }
 public void C(MyObject o) { ... }
}
```

How can I verify that method B() was invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `B` and `C` aren't virtual, then you won't be able to directly verify these methods with Moq, as they are tightly coupled to `A`.

You may however be able to verify the branch indirectly, e.g. if `B` and `C` do different things to Object `o`, then you may be able to detect this, or alternatively if `B` and `C` themselves invoke Mockable dependencies, e.g. if `B` invokes a `ILogger` and `C` invokes an ORM Update, then you can verify the branch indirectly through the presence of the indirect interactions.

Otherwise, I would suggest code refactoring, either:

- Make B and C `virtual`, so that they can be verified by Moq (possibly with a `CallBase=true`, if relevant to the test on the SUT)
- If B and C represent different concerns (in the `SOLID` sense), then consider other refactorings, such that the methods `B` and `C` themselves are relocated to mockable dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can verify if methods have been called on a mock object, but having an object moq itself is impossible.

If MyObject is indeed a mock object you can use:

```
mockObject.Verify(m => m.B(It.IsAny<Type>()), Times.Exacly(n))
```